# How I create Desktop (Windows) Client for My Android Chat App

Tags: android, flutter, chat, desktop-application, mobile-application

I'm going to create a college project on a P2P chat app like WhatsApp (Desktop with Mobile), And I unable to found how to create Windows Chat App for my Android Chat app that works on the same database as Telegram Desktop or WhatsApp Desktop App for their Mobile Apps.

[image]

I don't know about this, How to start this, And what technology I used for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to use [Flutter SDK](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install)

You can easily setup a chatapp, either your own using websockets or using Firebase (Google Cloud API) package.
If its fully P2P then you would have to implement webrtc.

It is very easy, I have used countless languages in the past Python, C#, C++, Javascript, React, Xamarin, Android etc... and, imho, **none** of them can compete with **Flutter for the architectural elegance, the time to market and, ice on the cake, the cross OS development capability**.

To be fair, I would say React Native would give you a short-term advantage on the job market (both in term of opportunity and salary) as it was (and still is) widely used by startups created in the 2010s, but that's not the purpose of your project.

Although desktop apps are still in beta it is improving very fast and I am quite confident that this would require minor changes to the code.

I have created a [project making use of websockets](https://github.com/agavrel/websocket). You can try to clone it and start building on it after spending about a week (intensively) learning about the different widgets of Flutter, its asynchronous system, and what are stateful widget.

In summary you would be using only one language (potentially no more than 10-20 .dart files) and of course one DB of your choice (you can get 1 year free with AWS MongoDB or Google Free Tier Firebase Database).

Android............DB....................Windows desktop
Flutter SDK......your choice......Flutter SDK

Let me know if you have any additional question!

Comment: this information is like a sea pearl for me.
I definitely use this information to create my project successfully, Thanks for your support.

Comment: if you like it you may select it as answer ;)